# writing onchange function in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to handle event for selected value changed in select box.

```
<%=  select_tag "vehicle", options_from_collection_for_select(@vid,"id","id"), :prompt => "Select vehicle" %>
```

Since remote_function is deprecated in rails 3.1, I wish to know how to write :onchange event and I want to write in ruby and not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this

```
<%=  select_tag "vehicle", options_from_collection_for_select(@vid,"id","id"), :prompt => "Select vehicle", :onchange => "my_function();" %>
```

This will do the job